# Not able to run Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Features

Tags: windows, powershell, window, firewall, windows-firewall

As part of automation of I am running the command `Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Features` using PowerShell with elevated permission (As admin) but its keep on failing with error. I know this command need the website access but IT team need the list of specefic website to unblock in firewall. I searched a lot but excluding these two (http://update.microsoft.com and http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com.) I am not able to find anything.

```
Add Windows feature failed with Error: The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed.
Installation of one or more roles, role services, or features failed. Error: 0x80072ee2
```